# Extend parent of position:absolute child to child's width

Tags: html, css

On http://jsfiddle.net/q8eDF/ I am trying to get a menu styled, however it's not quite perfect yet.

How do I get the red border of .dropdown-container expand also for the green area (i.e. the whole menu), the blue border of .dropdown-header extend to the right border of the .dropdown-item's (or, the .dropdown-item's extend to the border of .dropdown-header in case the header is wider than the widest item), all while allowing ~10px of space between the last character of .dropdown-header and .dropdown-arrow?

I don't care about BC, I'm fine as long as current FF and Chrome can run it.

HTML:

```
<div id="dd" class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown-header">Feed options<span class="dropdown-arrow">v</span></div>
  <div class="dropdown-items">
    <div class="dropdown-item">Reload</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item">Unsubscribe</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item">Reload from source</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-container {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid red;
position: relative;
}
.dropdown-items {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid green;
}
.dropdown-items {
margin: 5px 0px;
}
.dropdown-item {
margin: 3px 6px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-header {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-arrow {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to get rid of `position: absolute` on `.dropdown-items`. Any specific reason you're using absolute positioning?

Comment: Yes, anything other for position: messes up other menu items. I put an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ayh2d/

Comment: How about wrapping the whole navbar in a absolutely positioned container, then padding the `body` down: http://jsfiddle.net/ayh2d/2/? (example is a little rough, but the idea is there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a navbar is what you're after, I recommend wrapping the whole thing in an absoltely positioned container so it can float above other content:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div id="dd" class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="dropdown-header">
            Feed options<span class="dropdown-arrow">v</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-items">
            <div class="dropdown-item">Reload</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Unsubscribe</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Reload from source</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
}
.navbar > div { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top; 
}

body { 
    padding-top: 23px; 
}

.dropdown-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-header {
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-arrow {
    float: right;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayh2d/2/)